# can I use threading.local with concurrent.futures?

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert a program based on the [threading](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) standard module to the [concurrent.futures](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html) API.  It uses variables representing [threading.local](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.local)() objects ([more documentation](https://gist.github.com/tkaemming/5640332)).

Is it possible to use threading.local with concurrent.futures ? My first attempt failed.  Is there an equivalent construct ?

Comment: Can you explain how you're using `threading.local()`?

Comment: Well, I don't think there's any reason concurrent.futures will not work with threading.local(), as concurrent.futures AFAIK uses threading.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

The problem was that the concurrent.futures version of my program re-used existing threads when they became available, while the threading version did not.  This had some unexpected side effects, that are now resolved.